# Creating a local database from a script file?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to the whole database thing. I was wondering how I would go about using these 2 files below to get information into a local database in C#.

**If someone could create the database and email it to me I would be VERY VERY grateful!**

mssql.create.sql

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_Tb_Requests_Tb_Consumer]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsForeignKey') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Requests] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Tb_Requests_Tb_Consumer
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_Tb_Transactions_Tb_Consumer]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsForeignKey') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Transactions] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Tb_Transactions_Tb_Consumer
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_TB_Offers_Tb_Product]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsForeignKey') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TB_Offers] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_TB_Offers_Tb_Product
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_Tb_Requests_Tb_Product]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsForeignKey') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Requests] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Tb_Requests_Tb_Product
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_Tb_Transactions_Tb_Product]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsForeignKey') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Transactions] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Tb_Transactions_Tb_Product
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_TB_Offers_Tb_Supplier]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsForeignKey') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TB_Offers] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_TB_Offers_Tb_Supplier
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_Tb_Transactions_Tb_Supplier]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsForeignKey') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Transactions] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Tb_Transactions_Tb_Supplier
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[TB_Offers]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[TB_Offers]
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Tb_Consumer]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[Tb_Consumer]
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Tb_Product]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[Tb_Product]
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Tb_Requests]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[Tb_Requests]
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Tb_Supplier]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[Tb_Supplier]
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Tb_Transactions]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[Tb_Transactions]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_Offers] (
    [Supp_ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [Prod_ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [Price] [money] NULL ,
    [Quantity] [float] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Consumer] (
    [Con_ID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [Name] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [City] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Product] (
    [Prod_ID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [Name] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [MU] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Requests] (
    [Con_ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [Prod_ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [Price] [money] NULL ,
    [Quantity] [float] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Supplier] (
    [Supp_ID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [Name] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [City] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Transactions] (
    [Tran_ID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [Supp_ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [Con_ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [Prod_ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [Price] [money] NULL ,
    [Quantity] [float] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TB_Offers] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TB_Offers] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Supp_ID],
        [Prod_ID]
    )  ON [PRIMARY] ,
    CONSTRAINT [CK_TB_Offers] CHECK ([Price] > 0.00),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_TB_Offers_1] CHECK ([Quantity] >= 0)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Consumer] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tb_Consumer] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Con_ID]
    )  ON [PRIMARY] 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Product] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tb_Product] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Prod_ID]
    )  ON [PRIMARY] 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Requests] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tb_Requests] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Con_ID],
        [Prod_ID]
    )  ON [PRIMARY] ,
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Tb_Requests] CHECK ([Price] > 0.00),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Tb_Requests_1] CHECK ([Quantity] >= 0)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Supplier] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tb_Supplier] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Supp_ID]
    )  ON [PRIMARY] 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Transactions] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tb_Transactions] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Tran_ID]
    )  ON [PRIMARY] ,
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Tb_Transactions] CHECK ([Price] > 0.00),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Tb_Transactions_1] CHECK ([Quantity] > 0)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TB_Offers] ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TB_Offers_Tb_Product] FOREIGN KEY 
    (
        [Prod_ID]
    ) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tb_Product] (
        [Prod_ID]
    ),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TB_Offers_Tb_Supplier] FOREIGN KEY 
    (
        [Supp_ID]
    ) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tb_Supplier] (
        [Supp_ID]
    )
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Requests] ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Tb_Requests_Tb_Consumer] FOREIGN KEY 
    (
        [Con_ID]
    ) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tb_Consumer] (
        [Con_ID]
    ),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Tb_Requests_Tb_Product] FOREIGN KEY 
    (
        [Prod_ID]
    ) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tb_Product] (
        [Prod_ID]
    )
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Transactions] ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Tb_Transactions_Tb_Consumer] FOREIGN KEY 
    (
        [Con_ID]
    ) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tb_Consumer] (
        [Con_ID]
    ),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Tb_Transactions_Tb_Product] FOREIGN KEY 
    (
        [Prod_ID]
    ) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tb_Product] (
        [Prod_ID]
    ),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Tb_Transactions_Tb_Supplier] FOREIGN KEY 
    (
        [Supp_ID]
    ) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tb_Supplier] (
        [Supp_ID]
    )
GO
```

mssql.insert.sql

```
DELETE FROM TB_TRANSACTIONS;
DELETE FROM TB_OFFERS;
DELETE FROM TB_REQUESTS;
DELETE FROM TB_PRODUCT;
DELETE FROM TB_CONSUMER;
DELETE FROM TB_SUPPLIER;

--Suppliers
INSERT INTO TB_SUPPLIER VALUES('Joe','Madison')
INSERT INTO TB_SUPPLIER VALUES('Herman','Madison')
INSERT INTO TB_SUPPLIER VALUES('Bernstein','Madison')
INSERT INTO TB_SUPPLIER VALUES('Smith','Madison')

INSERT INTO TB_SUPPLIER VALUES('Redfield','Wausau')
INSERT INTO TB_SUPPLIER VALUES('Godman','Wausau')
INSERT INTO TB_SUPPLIER VALUES('James','Wausau')
INSERT INTO TB_SUPPLIER VALUES('Wells','Wausau')
INSERT INTO TB_SUPPLIER VALUES('Wolf','Wausau')

INSERT INTO TB_SUPPLIER VALUES('Thomas','Chicago')
INSERT INTO TB_SUPPLIER VALUES('Traiger','Chicago')

INSERT INTO TB_SUPPLIER VALUES('Strong','Stevens Point')
INSERT INTO TB_SUPPLIER VALUES('Deitel','Stevens Point')
INSERT INTO TB_SUPPLIER VALUES('Troelsen','Stevens Point')

INSERT INTO TB_SUPPLIER VALUES('Stronger','London')
INSERT INTO TB_SUPPLIER VALUES('Wolfgang','London')

INSERT INTO TB_SUPPLIER VALUES('Jones','Madison')
INSERT INTO TB_SUPPLIER VALUES('Jaques','Paris')

--Consumers
INSERT INTO TB_CONSUMER VALUES('Steel','New York')
INSERT INTO TB_CONSUMER VALUES('Hammer','New York')
INSERT INTO TB_CONSUMER VALUES('Iron','New York')

INSERT INTO TB_CONSUMER VALUES('Hoffer','Wausau')
INSERT INTO TB_CONSUMER VALUES('Gray','Wausau')
INSERT INTO TB_CONSUMER VALUES('Fisher','Wausau')
INSERT INTO TB_CONSUMER VALUES('Franklin','Wausau')
INSERT INTO TB_CONSUMER VALUES('Smith','Wausau')
INSERT INTO TB_CONSUMER VALUES('Schafer','Wausau')
INSERT INTO TB_CONSUMER VALUES('Johnson','Wausau')

INSERT INTO TB_CONSUMER VALUES('Jacob','Chicago')
INSERT INTO TB_CONSUMER VALUES('Metzker','Chicago')
INSERT INTO TB_CONSUMER VALUES('Boggs','Chicago')

--Products
INSERT INTO TB_PRODUCT VALUES('Computer','Pieces')
INSERT INTO TB_PRODUCT VALUES('Auto','Pieces')
INSERT INTO TB_PRODUCT VALUES('TV','Pieces')
INSERT INTO TB_PRODUCT VALUES('Milk','Gallon')
INSERT INTO TB_PRODUCT VALUES('Oil','Gallon')
INSERT INTO TB_PRODUCT VALUES('Orange','Lb')
INSERT INTO TB_PRODUCT VALUES('Truck','Pieces')
INSERT INTO TB_PRODUCT VALUES('Airplane','Pieces')

--Offers
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(1,1,799.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(1,2,7899.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(1,3,199.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(1,4,1.99,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(1,5,1.09,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(1,6,0.99,100)

INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(2,1,795.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(2,2,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(2,3,191.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(2,4,1.89,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(2,5,1.09,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(2,6,0.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(2,7,11.09,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(2,8,100.99,100)

INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(3,1,789.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(3,6,0.99,100)

INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(4,1,769.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(4,2,7899.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(4,3,199.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(4,6,0.99,100)

INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(5,1,799.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(5,2,7899.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(5,4,1.99,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(5,5,1.09,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(5,6,0.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(5,7,11.09,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(5,8,100.99,100)

INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(9,1,799.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(9,2,7809.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(9,3,189.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(9,4,1.99,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(9,5,1.19,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(9,6,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(9,7,11.09,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(9,8,100.99,100)

INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(8,1,799.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(10,1,7809.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(11,1,189.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(12,1,1.99,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(14,1,1.09,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(15,1,0.89,100)

INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(8,7,37990.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(10,7,80900.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(12,7,100000.99,10000)

INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(11,8,18.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(12,8,1.99,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_OFFERS VALUES(14,8,1.09,100000)

--Requests
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(1,1,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(1,2,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(1,3,196.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(1,4,1.90,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(1,5,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(1,6,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(1,7,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(1,8,89.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(2,1,790.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(2,2,7890.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(2,3,190.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(2,5,1.09,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(2,6,0.99,100)

INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(4,1,760.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(4,3,190.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(4,6,0.8,100)

INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(5,1,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(5,2,788.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(5,4,1.8,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(5,5,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(5,6,0.95,100)

INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(6,1,790.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(6,2,7809.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(6,3,186.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(6,4,1.99,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(6,5,1.09,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(6,6,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(7,1,799.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(7,2,7809.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(7,3,189.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(7,4,1.99,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(7,5,1.09,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_REQUESTS VALUES(7,6,0.89,100)

--Transactions
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,1,1,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,1,2,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,1,3,196.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,1,4,1.90,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,1,5,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,1,6,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,1,7,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,1,8,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,2,1,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,2,2,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,2,3,196.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,2,5,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,2,6,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,4,1,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,4,3,196.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,4,6,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,5,1,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,6,2,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,7,6,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,1,1,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,2,2,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,3,3,196.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,4,4,1.90,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,5,5,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,6,6,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,7,7,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,8,8,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,9,7,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(1,10,8,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,1,1,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,1,2,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,1,3,196.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,1,4,1.90,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,1,5,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,1,6,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,1,7,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,1,8,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,1,1,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,2,2,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,3,3,196.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,4,4,1.90,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,5,5,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,6,6,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,7,7,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,8,8,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,9,7,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,10,8,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,2,1,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,2,2,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,2,6,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,4,1,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,4,3,196.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,4,6,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,5,1,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,5,2,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(2,5,6,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,1,1,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,2,1,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,3,1,196.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,4,1,1.90,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,5,1,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,6,1,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,7,1,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,8,1,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,9,1,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,10,1,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,1,2,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,2,2,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,3,2,196.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,4,2,1.90,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,5,2,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,6,2,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,7,2,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,8,2,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,9,2,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,10,2,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,1,3,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,2,3,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,3,3,196.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,4,3,1.90,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,5,3,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,6,3,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,7,3,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,8,3,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,9,3,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,10,3,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,1,4,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,2,4,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,3,4,196.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,4,4,1.90,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,5,4,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,6,4,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,7,4,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,8,4,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,9,4,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,10,4,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,1,5,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,2,5,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,3,5,196.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,4,5,1.90,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,5,5,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,6,5,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,7,5,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,8,5,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,9,5,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,10,5,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,1,6,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,2,6,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,3,6,196.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,4,6,1.90,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,5,6,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,6,6,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,7,6,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,8,6,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,9,6,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,10,6,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,1,7,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,2,7,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,3,7,196.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,4,7,1.90,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,5,7,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,6,7,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,7,7,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,8,7,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,9,7,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,10,7,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,1,8,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,2,8,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,3,8,196.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,4,8,1.90,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,5,8,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,6,8,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,7,8,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,8,8,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,9,8,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(3,10,8,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(9,4,4,1.90,10000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(9,5,5,1.00,100000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(9,6,5,0.90,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(9,7,2,798.99,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(9,2,1,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(9,2,6,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(9,4,1,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(9,4,3,196.99,1000)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(9,4,6,0.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(9,5,1,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(9,5,2,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(9,5,6,99.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(11,1,2,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(11,5,4,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(11,7,6,99.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(13,2,2,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(13,5,4,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(13,8,7,99.90,100)

INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(15,2,2,798.99,100)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(15,5,4,7897.99,10)
INSERT INTO TB_TRANSACTIONS VALUES(15,8,7,99.90,100)
```

Comment: IMHO you should *use* queries included in these two files in MS-SQL console, not inside Visual Studio using C#...

Answer (score 2):

Those files are SQL scripts. All they do is create a set of tables and populate them. There is nothing in them to access the data in the database once created.

They are intended to be executed on a SQL database, most likely SQL Server.

This would normally be done by using [SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593).

Comment: I would assume he knows little about databases but his request is very specific. Insert SQL thru C# so suggesting to do it thru SQL Server Management Studio while legit shouldn't be an answer.

Comment: @MadBoy - It **is** an answer. I am answering to his _need_ rather than how he thinks he should address it.

Comment: Fair enough. I have addressed his question whether he really wanted it or not :-) Assuming he is going to execute only those scripts provided it would be more beneficent for him to use SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: I was wanting to do it through C# directly. I tried running them in Microsoft SQL Server Management but ran into errors. Can these files be run using CE? I cant even get the tables to insert :/

Comment: @Kevin - You really need to learn more about SQL Server. You need to have the correct permissions in order to run these. Yes, they should execute fine on CE.

Comment: @Oded is there a simple way to fix the permissions to get this done before i start getting more into SQL server?

Comment: @Kevin - I have no idea what issues you are facing, so can't tell.

Comment: @Oded 
Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 25501
> if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_Tb_Requests_Tb_Consumer]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsForeignKey') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Requests] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Tb_Requests_Tb_Consumer
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = if ]

Comment: @Oded 
Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 26100
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_Offers] (
       [Supp_ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
       [Prod_ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
       [Price] [money] NULL ,
       [Quantity] [float] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
The table name is not valid. [ Token line number (if known) = 1,Token line offset (if known) = 22,Table name = TB_Offers ]
There are those errors for every line. Nothing executes properly

Comment: @Kevin - Where are you trying to execute these from?

Comment: @Oded Microsoft SQL management studio. I created a local CE database and ran new query

Answer (score 1):

This is quick and dirty code but you can play with it a bit to get what you need

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test {
    internal class Class1 {
        public const string sqlDataConnectionDetails = "Data Source=SQL_SERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_NAME;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD";
        private void TestWrite() {
            const string preparedCommand =
                @"

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_Tb_Requests_Tb_Consumer]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsForeignKey') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Requests] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Tb_Requests_Tb_Consumer
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_Tb_Transactions_Tb_Consumer]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsForeignKey') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Transactions] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Tb_Transactions_Tb_Consumer
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_TB_Offers_Tb_Product]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsForeignKey') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TB_Offers] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_TB_Offers_Tb_Product
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_Tb_Requests_Tb_Product]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsForeignKey') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Requests] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Tb_Requests_Tb_Product
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_Tb_Transactions_Tb_Product]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsForeignKey') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Transactions] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Tb_Transactions_Tb_Product
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_TB_Offers_Tb_Supplier]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsForeignKey') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TB_Offers] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_TB_Offers_Tb_Supplier
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_Tb_Transactions_Tb_Supplier]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsForeignKey') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Transactions] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Tb_Transactions_Tb_Supplier
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[TB_Offers]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[TB_Offers]
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Tb_Consumer]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[Tb_Consumer]
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Tb_Product]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[Tb_Product]
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Tb_Requests]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[Tb_Requests]
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Tb_Supplier]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[Tb_Supplier]
GO

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Tb_Transactions]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [dbo].[Tb_Transactions]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_Offers] (
    [Supp_ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [Prod_ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [Price] [money] NULL ,
    [Quantity] [float] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Consumer] (
    [Con_ID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [Name] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [City] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Product] (
    [Prod_ID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [Name] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [MU] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Requests] (
    [Con_ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [Prod_ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [Price] [money] NULL ,
    [Quantity] [float] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Supplier] (
    [Supp_ID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [Name] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [City] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Transactions] (
    [Tran_ID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [Supp_ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [Con_ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [Prod_ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [Price] [money] NULL ,
    [Quantity] [float] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TB_Offers] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TB_Offers] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Supp_ID],
        [Prod_ID]
    )  ON [PRIMARY] ,
    CONSTRAINT [CK_TB_Offers] CHECK ([Price] > 0.00),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_TB_Offers_1] CHECK ([Quantity] >= 0)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Consumer] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tb_Consumer] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Con_ID]
    )  ON [PRIMARY] 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Product] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tb_Product] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Prod_ID]
    )  ON [PRIMARY] 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Requests] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tb_Requests] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Con_ID],
        [Prod_ID]
    )  ON [PRIMARY] ,
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Tb_Requests] CHECK ([Price] > 0.00),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Tb_Requests_1] CHECK ([Quantity] >= 0)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Supplier] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tb_Supplier] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Supp_ID]
    )  ON [PRIMARY] 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Transactions] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tb_Transactions] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Tran_ID]
    )  ON [PRIMARY] ,
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Tb_Transactions] CHECK ([Price] > 0.00),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Tb_Transactions_1] CHECK ([Quantity] > 0)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TB_Offers] ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TB_Offers_Tb_Product] FOREIGN KEY 
    (
        [Prod_ID]
    ) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tb_Product] (
        [Prod_ID]
    ),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TB_Offers_Tb_Supplier] FOREIGN KEY 
    (
        [Supp_ID]
    ) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tb_Supplier] (
        [Supp_ID]
    )
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Requests] ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Tb_Requests_Tb_Consumer] FOREIGN KEY 
    (
        [Con_ID]
    ) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tb_Consumer] (
        [Con_ID]
    ),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Tb_Requests_Tb_Product] FOREIGN KEY 
    (
        [Prod_ID]
    ) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tb_Product] (
        [Prod_ID]
    )
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tb_Transactions] ADD 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Tb_Transactions_Tb_Consumer] FOREIGN KEY 
    (
        [Con_ID]
    ) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tb_Consumer] (
        [Con_ID]
    ),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Tb_Transactions_Tb_Product] FOREIGN KEY 
    (
        [Prod_ID]
    ) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tb_Product] (
        [Prod_ID]
    ),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Tb_Transactions_Tb_Supplier] FOREIGN KEY 
    (
        [Supp_ID]
    ) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tb_Supplier] (
        [Supp_ID]
    )
GO
";
            using (SqlConnection varConnection = sqlConnectOneTime(sqlDataConnectionDetails)) {
                using (var sqlWrite = new SqlCommand(preparedCommand, varConnection)) {
                    sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        private static SqlConnection sqlConnectOneTime(string varSqlConnectionDetails) {
            var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(varSqlConnectionDetails);
            try {
                sqlConnection.Open();
            } catch {
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(new Form {
                                                                   TopMost = true
                                                               }, "Error connecting to database", "Error (000001)", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                if (result == DialogResult.No) {
                    if (Application.MessageLoop) {
                        Application.Exit(); // Use this since we are a WinForms app
                    } else {
                        Environment.Exit(1); // Use this since we are a console app// Use this since we are a console app
                    }
                } else {
                    sqlConnection = sqlConnectOneTime(varSqlConnectionDetails);
                }
            }
            return sqlConnection;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are SQL files containing SQL Server's dialect of SQL, T-SQL, so you'll need an instance of SQL Server to run them on - nothing to do with C#. If you don't have SQL Server, then you could look at downloading and installing the express version. Once you have this installed, then you will have an application called SQL Server Management Studio with which you can open and then execute these two files.

I'd suggest you buy a book on SQL Server and read the first few chapters to get familiar with it.

Comment: I tried running these files and i get an error, will they not work in SQLCE because of the format?

Comment: Also im doing this for an assingment tomorrow, i dont really have time to buy a book before then but i will definitally get one and start reading for future reference. And suggestions for books?